# RxSwift and static cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I'd like to use RxSwift in my project, but because I'm newbie I maybe misunderstand some principles. Its clear for me how to catch button presses or use rxswift with UITableView with dynamic cells (there are a lot of tutorials for that), but I don't understand how to use it with UITableView with **STATIC** cells - I'd like to develop something like iOS Settings.app. Could you show me example? Is it a good practice to use rxswift for it? Or maybe I should use something else?

Comment: Use rx to update views in cells, catch selection of table view in standard delegate method "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"

Answer (score 1):

You can drag a `@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!` from static table view cell button, So it's something like this:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    ...


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        button.rx.tap
            .subscribe()
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    ...
}
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

To handle static cells, you have to use a UITableViewController (which I assume you know) but you can still use the `rx` operators on its tableView.

Of course you don't need to use the `items` operator on it because the cells are already built, but you can still use `itemSelected` to determine which cell was tapped on:

```
final class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rx.itemSelected
            .subscribe(onNext: { print("selected index path \($0)") })
            .disposed(by: bag)
    }

    let bag = DisposeBag()
}
```